# Compiling Android project on a Centos server

Tags: android, gradle, server, centos

I want to build an android app on a Centos server using Gradle compiler but I get this while build.

```
    :app:compileDebugAidl FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:  
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:  
Process 'command '/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0/aidl'' finished with non-zero exit value 139
```

and this is the stacktarce

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
```

and a lot more that I can't put all of them , if you're looking for specefic thing let me know
and the last lines are:

```
 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
            ... 68 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0/aidl'' finished with non-zero exit value 139
            at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:119)
            at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.SourceSearcher.search(SourceSearcher.java:76)
            at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.compileAllAidlFiles(AndroidBuilder.java:1188)
            at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile.compileAllFiles(AidlCompile.java:130)
            at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile.doFullTaskAction(AidlCompile.java:191)
            ... 76 more
    Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0/aidl'' finished with non-zero exit value 139
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:43)
            at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.AidlProcessor.processFile(AidlProcessor.java:105)
            at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.SourceSearcher$1.call(SourceSearcher.java:96)
            at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.SourceSearcher$1.call(SourceSearcher.java:93)
    Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.0/aidl'' finished with non-zero exit value 139
            at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367)
            at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:41)
            ... 3 more


    BUILD FAILED
```

the build.gradle file inside the app directory is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pars_sharg"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/adad.jar')
    compile files('libs/urlimageviewhelper-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/zxing-2.1.jar')
    compile 'com.sayanpco.charge.library:sayan-charge:1.8'
}
```

Comment: Check your SDK, build tools and gradle plugins version. I had a similar error and I had to update all three to the latest versions.

Comment: Run with `--stacktrace` to get more information

Comment: @ÁlvaroPérezSoria the written project is compatible with android-sdk 23, the build tools is 23.0.0 and I haven't installed any Gradle plugins, I think.

Comment: Which gradle version do you have? and java JDK?

Comment: @ÁlvaroPérezSoria gradle is 2.14.1 and java JDK is 1_7

Comment: @JBirdVegas you can see the stack trace now.

Comment: @Amir, please include your `build.gradle` file

Comment: @JBirdVegas build.gradle is ready

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your targeting a very old version of android... way too old to be what your probably want.

Please update this part of your build.gradle

```
android {
    //...
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
    }
}
```

a more reasonable `minSdkVersion` & `targetSdkVersion` would be like this

```
android {
    //...
    defaultConfig {
        // Min doesn't have to be this high but
        // it's a reasonable `minSdkVersion`
        minSdkVersion 15
        // target should be the version of the build tools you are using
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
}
```